# Insert a part of a table into another table

Tags: sql

I have table A and table B, same schemas.

I want to insert certain rows from table A into table B. For example, insert into table B all rows from table A with column 'abc' > 10.

Couldn't figure out how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this

```
INSERT INTO B (supplier_id, supplier_name)
SELECT supplier_id, supplier_name FROM A
WHERE abc > 10;
```

Make sense?

Comment: The where clause needs the single quotes removed from the column name. Right now you are comparing the string 'abc' to see if it is greater than 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following notation:

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO ExistingTable (Col1, Col2...)
SELECT Something1, Something2... FROM Table1 WHERE ...
--ROLLBACK/COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

At first blush, I'd say something like:

```
Insert Into B
(Select * from A
Where abc > 10)
```